# Are mass gainers useful to meet calorie requirements?

Tags: bodybuilding, mass, ectomorph

I am trying to hit 3000 kcals. I get about 2000 cals from normal food. Is it ok to use mass gainer (like Optimum nutrition) to get the remaining? What are some side effects I should watch out for?

Answer (score 1):

I'd strongly suggest looking at the ingredients and avoiding mass gainers where the first few ingredients are dextrose, or some similar form of sugar. most of these products are just a scoop of whey protein and a lot of low glycemic sugar. Look for some that have healthy carbs like sweet potato or oat powder.   By the way, you can also make your own mass gainer.. blend some oats in a food processor to make "oat powder", and mix that with some casein protein(or whey protein), and its healthy mass gainer! you can also add peanut butter and a banana to make it test better and add more calories, but research all you can

Comment: thanks for the feedback. I am looking at the mass gainer [here](https://www.hollandandbarrett.com/shop/product/optimum-nutrition-serious-mass-vanilla-powder-60005293) and I don't see dextrose. Would you recommend it?

Comment: I am looking at [this one](https://www.bulk.com/uk/complete-mass-gainer.html?view=ppc&pid=3178&gclid=CjwKCAjwmrn5BRB2EiwAZgL9ovoWGKBDHmKveW7JDyIAq7V0t53yfE36xwlcM5JhhkrxUbdVlkTnHBoCNBoQAvD_BwE) as an alternative. It says it "uses scottish oats as aleternative to sugar-based dextrose or maltodextrin."

Comment: This second one looks pretty good!

Comment: thank you for the feedback - very much appreciated!! Just one question: at the bottom of the nutrition chart, it says: **Xylitol based table top sweetener. Excessive consumption may cause laxative effects. Do not exceed recommended use.** Is this equivalent to dextrose/similar forms? Given that I intend to take about 2-3 serving in a day, should I be worried about it?

Comment: If its not one of the main ingredients then it should be ok.. the issue with others is those 1200 calorie mass gainers might have 150 carbs which are pure sugar. This might just sweeten it, should be ok. I'd stick to the recommended servings though

Answer (score 1):

Don't buy mass gainers, make your own!

Whey protein, whole milk, a banana, a scoop of peanutbutter, and you are practically at 1000 kcals, dependent on how much of each ingredient you add.

Avoid mass gainers, they contain too much crap.

Answer (score 0):

the only side effects are digestive ones if the mass gainer is processed in a safe manner.

the worst thing you can expect happening to you is diarrhea in the most extreme case, or farting a little more in the most mild cases.

depending on how everything is processed, it can be carcinogenic, I would first inform myself by directly contacting the producer and asking how its made.